# How to set the mimetype value in web.xml dynamically

Tags: java, web-applications, tomcat, servlets

How can I set the mime-type dynamically through serveletContext object? (there is a setAttribute... can I use that and if so what would the attribute name be?

Basically, I want to override the mime-type that is specified in the web.xml either at servlet initialization time (via the Init method), or some other way in a programmatic manner as oppose to changing the web.xml entry statically.

My case scenario is as follows: By default web.xml file has the following mime-type for .log extensions:

```
<mime-mapping>
    <extension>log</extension>
    <mime-type>**text/plain**</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
```

I want to change that to:

```
<mime-mapping>
    <extension>oqcrlog</extension>
    <mime-type>**application/octet-stream**</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
```

How can I change this mime-type association in my web app under tomcat in a **programmatic** manner?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not possible, even if using Servlet 3.0 (tomcat 7).

But as mime-types are predefined you would normally just add that one there manually.